# Using Javascript to change CSS file being used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to change the CSS of the page whenever a list is being clicked. However whenever I try and do so the browser just shows the CSS as text and doesn't actually use it for the page. Looked at a bunch of answers on here but cant get any to work.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="character_sheet.php">Character</a></li>
  <li><a href="send_message.php">Send Message</a></li>
  <li><a href="view_messages.php">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="view_blog.php">View Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="history.php">History</a></li>
  <li><a id="test" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">Dark Theme</a></li>
  <li><a id="test2" href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">Red Theme</a></li>
  <li><a id="test3" href="styles3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">Light Theme</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").attr("href", "styles.css");
});​
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test2").attr("href", "styles2.css");
});​
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test3").attr("href", "styles3.css");
});​
</script>
```

EDIT:

I have tried doing what user neil said to do but whenever I implement the following I am unable to click on the list entries. The cursor does not change to the little hand with a finger you usually get hovering over links. Clicking does nothing.

```
<li><a class="test" data-src="styles.css">Dark Theme</a></li>
  <li><a class="test" data-src="styles2.css">Red Theme</a></li>
  <li><a class="test" data-src="styles3.css">Light Theme</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on('click', function(){
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + this.getAttribute('data-src') + '" type="text/css" />');
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT2:
I have implemented another users solution which still doesnt work on mine. If you are going to downvote my post please tell me why atleast, I would really like to fix this. My new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>D20-TABLEKEEPER</h1>
<form action="blurb.php">
    <input type="submit" value="BLURB" size="21">
</form>
</div>


<ul>
  <li><a href="character_sheet.php">Character</a></li>
  <li><a href="send_message.php">Send Message</a></li>
  <li><a href="view_messages.php">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="view_blog.php">View Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="history.php">History</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changeStyles" data-src="styles.css">Dark Theme</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changeStyles2" data-src="styles2.css">Red Theme</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changeStyles3" data-src="styles3.css">Light Theme</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".changeStyle").click(function(){
                        var style = $(".changeStyles").attr('data-src');
                        $('head').append('<link href="'+ style +'" rel="stylesheet">');
                });
                $(".changeStyle1").click(function(){
                        var style = $(".changeStyles2").attr('data-src');
                        $('head').append('<link href="'+ style +'" rel="stylesheet">');
                });
                $(".changeStyle1").click(function(){
                        var style = $(".changeStyles3").attr('data-src');
                        $('head').append('<link href="'+ style +'" rel="stylesheet">');
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Where you are clicking in `<script>..</script>` ?

Comment: I want it so when I click on the list entry it does it. The script has no physical output to click on.

Comment: You don't need to use the `$(document).ready()` for each code line. Just wrap what you want to do when the DOM is ready in an unique wrapper.

Comment: your question is not clear. Are you changing the css of the clicked <li> tag or what else

Comment: the answers below are only going to work as expected maybe the first time you click it. what you probably need ot do is replace an existing stylesheet rather than just adding every style on top the last one.

Comment: Having `<a href="styles.css">` in your page does not use those styles for your page.  That's just a link.

Comment: No I want it so when I click the theme in the list it changes to .CSS for the entire page.

Comment: *"but the cursor does not change to the icon"* - Icon, what icon?

Comment: "The cursor does not change" would be a better description. Like when you go to click a link, like the add comment button. The cursor will change to a hand with its finger out. My cursor does not do that after implementing the edit.

Comment: then the problem is or could be in your css files. That can easily be modfied using the cursor directive

Comment: adding href="#" made them clickable but they still do not change the CSS of the page.

Comment: @zoid230 If you put a breakpoint in at `$('head').append('`... and click a link, does the debugger stop here? Or, if you look at the page html in your developer tools, do you see the new `<link>`  element get created?

Comment: @neilsimp1 I am not using a debugger sadly, I am running this live from my raspberryPi and would not know how to do those with it as I am new to using it.

Comment: The way this is structured currently if the user clicked the same link 3 times would it not try to append the same stylesheet 3 times? Similarly, if they click each link 3 times would there not then be 3 copies of each stylesheet?

Comment: I was hoping it would overwrite the previous one, not just add one ontop. Do you have a work around?

Comment: Are there other css files referenced in the `<head>` that you don't want replaced? If not, you could just simply do `$('head').find('link').remove();` before calling the `$('head').append`. If you have other css files you need to keep in there, then you'd have to get more creative.

Comment: @zoid230 - look at the `<script>` tag in your latest edit. You've got both a script inside of it and `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js` as an attribute. You need to break those into two tags: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(...`

Comment: In **Edit-2**, `<a href="#" class="changeStyles" data-src` class name is `changeStyles`. In `<script>`, you used `changeStyle`. So, you are not calling even right class. @zoid230 It's very easy to say *it's not working*.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Changing the class error still didnt fix it sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery I can offer no real assistance but with vanilla javascript it is quite easy to do. Assign an id to the original stylesheet so that it can be targeted easily, use `querySelectorAll` to identify the links used to switch css and assign an event listener to each. The code below also stores the selected value in `localStorage` so that the user's choice persists across pages / sessions.

Assume three stylesheets ( all in same directory as current page, otherwise paths need to be added ) named `styles.css`,`styles2.css` and `styles3.css` which, for pure simplicity are as follows:

```
styles.css
----------
html, html *{
    background:red;
    color:white;
}
styles2.css
-----------
html, html *{
    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
}
styles3.css
-----------
html, html *{
    background:green;
    color:orange;
}



<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>css style switcher - no jQuery</title>
            <link id='style' href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet'>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function bindEvents(){

                    var css=document.getElementById('style');
                    var col=document.querySelectorAll('a.changeStyle');

                    /* iterate through collection and assign listener */
                    for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].onclick=function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();/* prevent jumping to top of page etc */
                        var el=typeof(e.target)!='undefined' ? e.target : e.srcElement;

                        /* assign style attributes */
                        css.href=el.dataset.style;
                        css.rel=el.dataset.rel;
                        css.type=el.dataset.type;

                        /* store reference to style selected in localstorage */
                        localStorage.setItem( 'style', el.dataset.style );
                    };

                    /* if there is a reference to the user's css choice in storage, assign it */
                    if( localStorage.getItem( 'style' )!=null ) css.href=localStorage.getItem( 'style' );
                }

                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='character_sheet.php'>Character</a></li>
          <li><a href='send_message.php'>Send Message</a></li>
          <li><a href='view_messages.php'>Messages</a></li>
          <li><a href='view_blog.php'>View Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href='history.php'>History</a></li>

          <li><a href='#' class='changeStyle' data-style='styles.css' data-type='text/css' data-rel='stylesheet'>Dark Theme</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='changeStyle' data-style='styles2.css' data-type='text/css' data-rel='stylesheet'>Red Theme</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='changeStyle' data-style='styles3.css' data-type='text/css' data-rel='stylesheet'>Light Theme</a></li>

          <li><a href='index.php'>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: YES!. Thank you I managed to get this working, I didnt add the id to my link at the top in the header the first time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see anywhere where you're binding a `click`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on('click', function(){
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + this.getAttribute('data-src') + '" type="text/css" />');
    });
});
```

And your html

```
<li><a class="test" data-src="styles.css">Dark Theme</a></li>
<li><a class="test" data-src="styles2.css">Red Theme</a></li>
<li><a class="test" data-src="styles3.css">Light Theme</a></li>
```

This way, on any `.test` click, you append a `<link>` for the css to your `head`.

Comment: I tried it this way before and I am getting the same issue now. When I implement this I can no longer click on the list. I can hover over them but the cursor does not change to the icon when you have a click able object underneath.

Comment: You can get the cursor by either putting `href="#"` on the `a` tags, or with the css `cursor:pointer;`. I took the href out of the `a` tags because you don't want it opening the css file as a new link, you just want a link appended in your html. Does it not work when you click on it, regardless of the cursor?

Comment: No this does not work, clicking on the link does nothing. I will append the href and try that now.
EDIT:
I now get the cursor, but clicking on the list still does not change the CSS

Comment: If I may add *my 2 cents*. Maybe adding `href="#"` could help here. Edit: ah, I see you have lol

Comment: I wasnt fibbing when I said I have tried a few solutions posted online and have already tried this. Could there be another issue?

Comment: you originally tagged as php so check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your developer console. @zoid230

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in head section of the page.

Eg

```
$("a").click(function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />');
    });
```

Please refer this tutorial

http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery

Comment: I tried to do this but it didnt work. See above answer by neil.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it. And, it was working.

**HTML Page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>asd</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="changeStyle1" data-src="style.css">style1</a> 
        <a class="changeStyle" data-src="style1.css">style1</a>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".changeStyle").click(function(){
                        var style = $(".changeStyle").attr('data-src');
                        $('head').append('<link href="'+ style +'" rel="stylesheet">');
                });
                $(".changeStyle1").click(function(){
                        var style = $(".changeStyle1").attr('data-src');
                        $('head').append('<link href="'+ style +'" rel="stylesheet">');
                });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
a {color:red;}
```

**style1.css**

```
a {color:green;}
```

Comment: Okay. What issues may I be having if this doesnt work with me? I am beginning to think it has to be come other issue then. I implemented this just as the way you sent it and it isnt working.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show my implementation of your code.